# Timezone is empty if in Los Angeles

Tags: swift, timezone, location, mapkit

Why this code is returning empty for timezone when user is in US..?
Works perfectly in rest of countries.

```
// Get local time zone
let localTimeZoneAbbreviation = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? ""
let indexStartOfText = localTimeZoneAbbreviation.index(localTimeZoneAbbreviation.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) // 3
let timeZone = localTimeZoneAbbreviation.substring(from: indexStartOfText)
print("TimeZone:",timeZone)
```

I need result in format of number:

"-7" for Los Angeles

"-4" for New York

"+2" for Hamburg

etc.

Comment: Why are you parsing strings? Use the `secondsFromGMT` method of `TimeZone`.

Comment: How to extract what I need from secondsFromGMT and to be exact in all over the world

Comment: You can use DateFormatter and set `dateFormat = "x"`

Comment: `let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "x"
dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // "-03"`

Comment: @Leo Yes bot it need to be without 0. In your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abbreviation comes out as PDT with nothing after it for my location.  So, there's no offset to get.

You can get the offset using the seconds like rmaddy said.

```
let seconds = TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()
let hours = seconds / 3600
let minutes = abs(seconds / 60) % 60
let timezoneDiff = String(format: "%+.1d:%.2d", hours, minutes)
print(timezoneDiff)
```

Make sure to account for locations that are not an exact number of hours different. Some are 30 minutes. There may be others too.

Comment: This is totally right, but in this case server wants only round numbers. I was thinking to check value like 'let check = timeZoneInt > 0 ? 1 : timeZoneInt == 0 ? 0 : -1;' and than manipulate in any format server needs in any case.